# Nested LinerLayout in Custom Dialog not showing up

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

Im trying to create a custom dialog box which contains main LinearLayout which has 2 nested LinearLayout inside it which contains ImageView and TextView.

But the problem is the None of the LinearLayout's are showing up.I'm not even getting any errors and Application is not crashing.

Thank You.

Below is the code segment related to this problem:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        ll_main = new LinearLayout(AddFreebie.this);
        ll_main.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ll_main.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        ll_main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        ll_bpic = new LinearLayout(AddFreebie.this);
        ll_bpic.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ll_bpic.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        ll_bpic.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        iv_bpic = new ImageView(AddFreebie.this);
        iv_bpic.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tv_bpic = new TextView(AddFreebie.this);
        tv_bpic.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tv_bpic.setText("Browse phone for pictures..");

        ll_bpic.addView(iv_bpic);
        ll_bpic.addView(tv_bpic);

        ll_cpic = new LinearLayout(AddFreebie.this);
        ll_cpic.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ll_cpic.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        ll_cpic.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        iv_cpic = new ImageView(AddFreebie.this);
        iv_cpic.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tv_cpic = new TextView(AddFreebie.this);
        tv_cpic.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tv_cpic.setText("Take pictures using camera.");
        ll_cpic.addView(iv_cpic);
        ll_cpic.addView(tv_cpic);

        ll_main.addView(ll_bpic);
        ll_main.addView(ll_cpic);

        builder.setView(ll_main);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                // MyActivity.this.finish();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```

Comment: Is there any reason your adding everything by code and don't inflate it from an XML view?

Comment: @eric.itzhak from xml view? i didnt get you.You mean create a dedicated layout for the dialog and do builder.setView(R.layout.dialog_view) something like this?
Also will it be not the same thing though?
Thanks for the response.

Comment: Ya it will be the same but then there will be no reason for a layout ti disappear and alot easier to manage.

Comment: @eric.itzhak alrighty lemme try it.i'll post about how did it go.Thanks for the response.

Comment: i just used TextViews directly as LinearLayouts are still not showing up :(

Answer (score 2):

I could be incorrect, But I dont think an AlertDialog is what you really want to use in this case.  If you read the Developer pages on AlertDialogs, they are really to be used for small 0, 1, 2, or 3 button alert windows, and arent really meant to have their own truly custom interfaces.  Here are some links on AlertDialogs

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-alertdialog-your-android-application

To do what you want to do I think you either want to use a Diaglog, or a PopupWindow

Link to creating custom dialogs:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Link to creating a custom popover window (I have used these in the past):
http://www.mobilemancer.com/2011/01/08/popup-window-in-android/

Comment: Actually i did visited the second link and than started using Dialogs.
In my other project i have EditText(this was not surrounded by LinearLayout) inside Dialog with two buttons and its showing up and its functioning properly.
You can modify almost all the examples shown there and im trying to do that but i don't know why LinearLayout is not showing up.
Thanks for the response :)

Comment: I had to settle with "Adding a list" thingi from Link#2.LinearLayout are still not showing up so i added TextViews directly but i still need to find a way in order to add ImageView in from of both textViews